# Accessing a pointer to a derived class when it is not created

Tags: c++

Why referring to a pointer to a derived class that has not yet been created is valid, but not undefined behavior.
[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/zv38Gc4ar)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    int a;
     void foo() {
        std::cout << "A = " << a << std::endl;
     }
};

struct B : public A{
    int b;
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "B = " << b << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    A *a = new A();
    B *b = static_cast<B*>(a);

    a->foo(); // cout A = 0
    b->foo(); // cout B = 0
    
    b->b = 333;
    
    b->foo(); // cout B = 333
    a->foo(); // cout A = 0
}
```

Should a pointer to a derived class be undefined?

Comment: Why do you think that's not undefined behavior?

Comment: What is an "undefined pointer"?

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer to a derived class that does not actually point to such a derived class is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" does not mean any particular behaviour. It is impossible to observe the absence of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your Godbold link is not relevant, because as menioned above this is UB and any compiler can do whatever it chooses.

Comment: try to compile with `-O3 -Wall -Werror` to get a rather enlightening error message https://godbolt.org/z/6WfKsTb8T  Then consider that the code has the exact same issue also without `-O3`.

Comment: Undefined behavior does not mean your code is guaranteed to crash or do something weird. The worst behavior of UB is when it appears to work even though its totally broken as far as the language says.

Comment: actually the error message is rather funny :)

Comment: Beginners seem to keep believing that undefined behaviour means "the program should crash or do something gruesome".    In reality, it just means that the standard doesn't articulate any requirements.   It is quite common for instances of undefined behaviour to appear to "work correctly" and not do anything gruesome - and this question appears to be based on an example of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with `-O3 -Werror -Wall` to get the following message from gcc:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:25:8: error: array subscript 'B[0]' is partly outside array bounds of 'unsigned char [4]' [-Werror=array-bounds]
   25 |     b->b = 333;
      |     ~~~^
<source>:19:18: note: object of size 4 allocated by 'operator new'
   19 |     A *a = new A();
      |                  ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The message is somewhat funny, becuase it leaks some gcc implementation details by mentioning a `unsigned char [4]` when there is none. However, if you consider what is wrong in your code, the message nails it....

In memory, a `B` object looks like this (very simplified):

```
  A 
  B
```

It has an `A` subobject and after that comes the `B` members. Now it happens that `A` is of size `4` (could be different but thats what it is with gcc).

When you write `b->b`. Then `b` points to an `A`  (not to ba `B`), but you pretend that it does point to a `B`. Hence when the compiler tries to apply the offset to the pointer to reach the member, this offset is larger than the size of the object. The compiler realizes that something cannot be right.

---

However, this is error message nothing more than an interesting curiosity. The compiler is not required to diagnose your mistake because your code has undefined behavior.

When your code has undefined behavior, anything can happen. The worst case is that the code appears to be fine and work as expected.

Why does your code compile and work ok? It does not. `b` does not point to a `B`. Your code could print `"Hello World"` to the console as well, it could erase your hard drive or really anything could happen. Only if your code has no undefined behavior there is a guarantee what your program will do.

Comment: Also worth noting that _most likely_ (but not guaranteed), what actually happens is that the `b->b = 333` overwrites the 4 bytes of memory after the `A` object. Which, as long as noting important is there, seems to work - at least until you do more in the program, and those 4 bytes actually start containing stuff that should not be overwritten, at which point you can start chasing "magic" bugs stemming from unrelated variables that seem to change value with nobody writing to them.

Comment: @Frodyne yes, though apparently the compile does detect the issue and thus might even remove `b->b = 333;` entirely. Its just not an optimization a valid program benefits a lot from, hence unlikely that the compiler will do it even with `-O3`

Answer (score 5):

`static_cast`ing a pointer to a pointer-to-derived-class when the pointed-to object isn't actually a base class subobject of an object of the derived type, as you are doing with the cast in `B *b = static_cast<B*>(a);`, *does* have undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior does not mean that you are guaranteed to get an error or unintended behavior. Undefined behavior does however mean that you won't have any guarantee for the intended behavior either.